# 3D plot of a heat distribution in a cube

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a .csv file with temperature values in the nodes of the cube. The cube size is 100х100х100 (.csv file contains 1.000.000 values), while $ 0 \leq x,y,z \leq 1 $. How can I plot a 3D heat map of temperature distribution in my cube?

Comment: [ListDensityPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html) could be a possibility.

Comment: Thank you. I`m trying to use this function, but I have an error (not a valid dataset). I think that this is due to the data format in my .csv file. Now my .csv file contains 1m rows and each row has a format: z,y,x,f. 
I use the following code: 

data = Import["output.txt" ,"Table"]

ListDensityPlot3D[data]

Comment: @andre314 It gives "List"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`ListDensityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot3D.html) assumes its data is in the format of `{x, y, z, f}`, and this data is in the form `{z, y, x, f}`, we need to change the order of the elements.

```
data = Import["data.csv", "CSV"];
ListDensityPlot3D[data /. {z_, y_, x_, f_} :> {x, y, z, f}]
```

For example

```
data = {#3, #2, #1, 1/Norm[{##}]} & @@@ Tuples[Range[0.01, 1, 0.1], 3];
ListDensityPlot3D[data /. {z_, y_, x_, f_} :> {x, y, z, f}]
```

[image]

And if you're using a version before 10.2, you can make an animation of rising through each `z` slice.

```
Export["data.csv", {#3, #2, #1, 1/Norm[{##}]} & @@@ Tuples[Range[0.01, 1, 0.01], 3]];
data = Import["data.csv", "CSV"];
zdata = GatherBy[data, First];
ListDensityPlot[
 #1 /. {z_, y_, x_, f_} :> {x, y, f},
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
 PlotLabel -> "z = " <> ToString[0.01 First@#2],
 BaseStyle -> 11,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
] &~MapIndexed~zdata // ListAnimate
```